# How to Update OpenGL with Intel graphics card Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, opengl

So I got my desktop back up and running and I wanted to play TF2, so I installed Steam, got the game and when it starts up I get

```
Could Not Find Required OpenGL Entry Point 'GLColormaskindexedEXT'! Either Your Video Card Is Unsupported Or Your OpenGL Driver Needs To Be Updated.
```

My Open GL in terminal says

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G33 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Is your system 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: 64 bit, with 8gb ram

Answer (score 5):

You can upgrade your graphical stack by running

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Also I suggest upgrading kernel by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i put that in it gives me Unable to locate package libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopi

Comment: @Soren You were not careful when selecting. You did not copy the last character.

Comment: It Still Doesnt Work, and i know my card will support it

Comment: I registered to upvote this.