# How to update OpenGL on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Intel graphic card

Tags: 14.04, opengl, mesa

I am trying to run Supertuxkart >= 0.9.2. It says that my video driver is too old. It wants OpenGL version 3 or greater. So I am trying to update OpenGL.

I have seen other posts about this issue (e.g. [How to Update OpenGL with Intel graphics card Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643140/how-to-update-opengl-with-intel-graphics-card-ubuntu-14-04) ), but none is working. So I am asking here.

The last thing I did was:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-xenial libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-xenial libgles2-mesa-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386 libegl1-mesa-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial libgbm1-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial
```

This updated mesa. I now have

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 11.2.0
```

However, supertuxkart still says I have OpenGL 2:

```
[info   ] IrrDriver: OpenGL version: 2.1
[info   ] IrrDriver: OpenGL vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
[info   ] IrrDriver: OpenGL renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
[info   ] IrrDriver: OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 11.2.0
```

My graphic card is:

```
$ lspci
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
...
```

Why OpenGL was not updated?

Thanks in advance.

**Update** 
Thanks Doug. Indeed, my graphic card does not support OpenGL version 3 or greater. I have verified it using [OpenGL Extension Viewer](https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/203876689-How-to-verify-that-the-Driver-of-the-Graphics-Card-supports-OpenGL-3-2#gsc.tab). So, this is why nothing was working for updating OpenGL.

Comment: That gpu only supports 2.1, so to 'update' get newer hardware.